# Should we roll up the details in this question into its title?

Tags: discussion, editing

I was reading this question on my phone today: [extreme slow wifi on ubuntu 16.04](https://askubuntu.com/questions/781306/extreme-slow-wifi-on-ubuntu-16-04)

Within the body I learned the WiFi card is a `rtl8723be` which I don't own. Had `Realtek 8732be` been in the title I wouldn't have wasted my time.

Would it make sense to roll the details up into the title to make it quicker for people? After all the title is extremely generic.

Answer (score 13):

## YES!!

Please do make edits like that. As it is anyone suffering from slow wifi is likely to click hopefully on that question and the majority of them will be wasting their time.

Putting hardware information in the title also hopefully suggests to those people suffering from slow wifi who might be interested in this question that they need to investigate their hardware, rather than blaming Ubuntu for having slow wifi in general and posting a question with no hardware details claiming "I tried solutions I read here and none worked" (because those solutions were for other wireless hardware than that they are using), or not posting a question and giving up on Ubuntu altogether...

**Better titles make better search results**, and that helps everyone.

Comment: Done and Done..